# chess xskak looping adding arrows

Tags: chess

To follow up chess movements using xskak looping, I would like to add arrows from the square a piece moves from to the square it moves to. Can the following code be adjusted to do so?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chess}
\begin{center}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 Bg7 4.e4 d6 5.Nge2 O-O 6.Ng3 c6 7.Be2 a6 8.a4 a5 9.h4 h5 10.Be3 Na6 11.f3 e5 12.d5 Nd7 13.Nf1 Ndc5 14.Nd2 Qb6 15.Qb1 Nb4 16.Nb3 Ncd3+ 17.Kd2 Qxe3+}
\xskakloop[step=1,showlast]{
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[normalboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}
\end{tabular}\quad}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Sure, there is even an example in the documentation. Search for \getmovestyles.